# Tkinter link Intvar() with a function and button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

As the title suggests, I'm trying to make a counter with `IntVar()`,so I've tried this.

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
    root.geometry('200x50')
    root.title('Home')

    #starts here
    var = IntVar()
    text = 'Count: ' + str(var.get())

    b1 = Button(root, text='Test', command=fun)
    b1.pack()
    l1 = Label(root, text=text)
    l1.pack()

    mainloop()

def fun():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print('test')

main()
```

But I got confused, I want to make it count the printings and show the value in the label.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to count the number of times 'test' is printed, you can update the l1 widget with `l1['text'] = var` after updating. To update, you can fetch the variable of intvar and then add 1 to it. Here's some code:

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
    root.geometry('200x50')
    root.title('Home')

    #starts here
    var = IntVar()
    text = 'Count: ' + str(var.get())

    b1 = Button(root, text='Test', command=lambda: fun(l1, var))
    b1.pack()
    l1 = Label(root, text=text)
    l1.pack()

    mainloop()

def fun(l1, var):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print('test')
        var.set(var.get()+1)
        l1['text'] = 'Count: ' + str(var.get())

main()
```

Comment: thanks it worked. Do u know how to make the counter appears as it rises, I mean, not showing the final result, but going from 1 2 3 ... 10.

Comment: Import the time module and use time.sleep(n) where n is the number of seconds you want it to wait between counts

Comment: where to implement it exactly please ?

Comment: import time at the top. time.sleep(1) before print('test')